# Reverse engineer a scan tool to display what commands it sends

Tags: engine, obd-ii, abs, scan-tool, bcm

I came across this video:
youtube.com/watch?v=VtMvccqE8ks

Any idea/resources how to build this setup? I am not much interested in monitoring the CAN bus for commands (headers or CAN IDs) of power window, AC temperature, fan speed etc., but more interested in seeing what command does a scan tool send if it has to check for DTCs for ABS or BCM or battery control module.

I have tried monitoring CAN bus and have been quite successful in pulling out CAN IDs for AC fan speed, AC temperature, Power windows, parking brakes, gear in which the car is etc., but monitoring CAN bus never gave me DTCs of ABS, BCM, Airbags etc. So, reverse engineering a scan tool feels like a plausible solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Reverse engineer the manufacturer specific protocol on OBD2 for acquiring enhanced vehicle data](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/39093/how-to-reverse-engineer-the-manufacturer-specific-protocol-on-obd2-for-acquiring)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not maintenance related. Reverse-engineering questions are off-topic.